# Run an AppleScript from a server/in the cloud

Tags: applescript, server

Is there a possibility to run AppleScripts from a server or from a cloud service?
I want to have some scripts that can run if my computer is sleeping/off.

I looked around a bit on Google, but haven't found anything promising.
If this doesn't exist I basically need to remove the password from my computer and wake up the computer whenever the script needs to run.

Comment: I would love to hear how you are going to run scripts on a computer that is off.

Comment: The obvious question to start with would be: what do these scripts actually do?

Comment: One of the scripts basically just has to click a button on a website at a given time.
@Scott, I asked for a server/cloud service, didn't I?

Comment: Sounds an odd way to pass one's time. What does clicking the button do? If it's just a simple form POST, a simple `curl` command scheduled via `cron` on any old budget Linux machine would do it. If it's some fancy JavaScripty wizamajig that requires automating a web browser then there are cross-platform tools for doing that too. Either way, OS X server-side is a complete joke: mainstream hosting providers all sell Linux/Windows for a reason. The only Mac offerings will be specialist boutiques who'll likely charge through the nose for a crappy product.

Comment: TBH, if it was me I'd just get a very low-cost, low-power computer like a Raspberry Pi or something and plug it in at home as an always-on device. Or, if you've already got a NAS server on your home network, you could see if you can run the script on that.

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on what you want to do with the script. There are a few options.

1. You can use 'stay open' script bundles that, for example, check a certain folder and run when you interact with this folder
2. You can launch certain scripts when the server boots.

You need to have a server that is always on for this to work. I have this running myself and it works just fine. However, as I said before, it largely depends on what you want to do with your scripts.